# XML Schema: uniqueness of subnode attribute values ONLY within EACH parent node?

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd, xml-validation

#### Objective:

For a schema I am creating, I would like to have a uniqueness constraint that checks for uniqueness  only within each parent node, as opposed to checking the entire schema for instances of the subnode.  I think this is best illustrated by example, see below xml.

#### Problem:

The xpath I'm using checks for uniqueness against all instances of `<subnode value="x">`, whereas I want it to check uniqueness against only instances of `<subnode value="x">` that are children of, and here's the clencher, *separate* instances of `<globalElement>`

#### XML with Desired Error:

```
<globalElement>
    <subnode value="1" />
    <subnode value="2" />
</globalElement>

<globalElement>
    <subnode value="1" />            <!-- Desired error here -->
    <subnode value="1" />            <!-- Desired error here -->
</globalElement>
```

#### XML with Current Error:

```
<globalElement>
    <subnode value="1" />           <!-- Error here -->
    <subnode value="2" />
</globalElement>

<globalElement>
    <subnode value="1" />            <!-- Error here -->
    <subnode value="1" />            <!-- Error here -->
</globalElement>
```

#### XML Schema (1.0):

```
<xs:element name="rootElement">
    <xs:complexType>
         <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" >
             <xs:any namespace="##targetNamespace"  />
         </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>       
     <xs:unique name="name_check">
          <xs:selector xpath=".//prefix:globalElement/prefix:subnode" />
          <xs:field xpath="@value" />
     </xs:unique>
</element>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unique constraint in schema is quite simple if you keep it simple. If you want every B within an A to have a unique value for C (e.g. every person within a country to have a unique value for passport number), then you should define the constraint at the level of element A, the selector should select B relative to A, and the field should select C relative to B.

Comment: Upon re-reading, I think this answer is similar to Jirka's, but more concise, hence the accept. My uniqueness checks did work once I placed the check within the parent element `<anyGlobalElement>`.  Thanks

Comment: Thanks. I always prefer to explain the principles and leave the originator to write the code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should define unique constraint on that parent element - in this case on globalElement

```
<xs:element name="GlobalElement">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="SubNode" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:attribute name="value" use="required"/>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:unique name="name_check">
        <xs:selector xpath="SubNode"/>
        <xs:field xpath="@value"/>
    </xs:unique>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: This worked and didn't work. Here's where it went right: nesting the uniqueness check within the element performs the type of check I that results in my desired output.  Now, here's where it didn't work:  this solution isn't compatible with my schema design, ie, `<any>`.

My `<globalElement>` is in the namespace, but imported into the validating document using an `<include>`. For some reason, the uniqueness checker isn't imported with it.

Comment: Update: Placing the uniqueness check did work inside `<globalElement>` worked, even with the `<include>`, I just forgot to add the prefixes in the included schema. Hope that makes sense. Thanks for the help.